# Wordpress Nested loop: Loops twice instead of once

Tags: wordpress, loops, nested, duplicates

I'm trying to achieve this

Author.php

- Author Loop:

  - Posts loop
  - Hobbies loop
  - schedule loop

The author.php template file has the author loop.
I need to loop through some custom post types for the author, then i'll put them into their own tabs.

However, when I put a query inside the Authors loop, it loops twice & i can't figure out why.

This is the loop(s) i'm using:

```
          <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>



            <div class="twelvecol first clearfix"><hr />


              <?php $looped = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ));
               if ( $looped->have_posts() ) { 
                   while ( $looped->have_posts() ) { 
                       $looped->the_post();
                       the_title();the_content();
                   }
               }
               wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
           </div>
```

Am I missing something that'll stop it from looping twice?

---

#### Notes:

I have to have these loops within the AUTHORS LOOP because they are specific to that author, i don't want STEVE's posts to show up on HARRY's page etc

- There might be several authors added and removed throughout the sites life, so it has to be dynamic, i can include an author in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much discussion and staring at the screen, it seems that the main Author Loop contains a WHILE, then in the nested loops, the queries also had a while.

Now from what i've gathered, the first WHILE asks how many posts the Author has created, then loops though it that many times,

The WHILE in the nested loops act like normal.

So I ended up with the amount of posts in the nested loop, LOOPED by it's parent WHILE...

If the Author had posted 5 posts, there would be 5 copies of the nested loops.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
```

Hope this helps people in the future with this issue!

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest loops like this you need to ad an argument to the `WP_Qwery`.
Check the global `$wp_query` for the current author and include that in the WP_Query.

This should be enough to get you started.
If you have questions or need more information, ask.

Comment: I don't need to include the Author in the post as it's on the Author page, so that is in the main loop, what i have discovered though, is that the WHILE on the authors loop isn't needed. What that does is loop the posts for as many posts as the author has created. So 3 posts = 3 times repeated, 5 posts = 5 times repeated!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the external loop at all (loop = more than one iteration). Just add the [`author`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters) ID as a parameter to the query.

Comment: I'd tried that, but it doesn't seem to like it. Using the get_author_meta function in a query doesn't separate the posts & is more leg work that what i've manage to come up with! The first WHILE in the Authors loop should be there